# How to design this domain model?

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

So I've the following Domain:

- Applications and Versions, they are actually software applications
- Devices, the devices on which the applications are installed
- Installed Applications on Devices
- Notification Subscription by installed Applications

So far, I've end up with the following model:

- `Application` entity, which is defined by a name, an os and a type
- `Version` value object, which basically wraps version informations (major, minor, etc.)
- `Release` entity, which is a composed object referencing an Application entity and embedding a Version value object
- `Device` entity, which is identified by a serial number
- `NotitificationSubscription` entity (to allow me to Query by attribute)

Now I'm wondering how to "associate" `Device` entity, `Release` and the `NotificationSubscription` because it should be associated to an "installed" `Release` on a `Device` and include some extra information (like an authentication token).

Given the limitation of my ORM (Doctrine2) & RDMS (MySQL) I'm stuck at how to find a good design.

Imagine the following workflow:

1. I fetch the `Device` entity from Database identified by its Serial Number
2. I determine if the `Release` the `Device` is running from is already associated with it, if no, I create an association
3. I need then to add or remove a `NotificationSubscription` for the current Device Release association

My problem is I end up with much indirection.

To allow me to set extra data to the association, I created an Association Class which is itself an Entity referencing both a Device and a Release.

A device may have different Release installed and running on it, so for example, I don't know how to query the following information: "Fetches all the notification subscriptions for the current release for the current device"

I obviously added a method in a Repository `findSubscriptionsByDeviceAndRelease($device, $release);` which means that I can query this information by both using the repository and through the graph `$device->getInstalledReleases()->filter($identifiedRelease)->getNotificationSubscriptions();`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple: you don't need a domain model here, you just need a good entity-relationship model. You probably don't need Doctrine either, since sql queries should be simple enough.